# How to handle dynamic error messages coming in an application

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, testng

I am facing an issue while automating a web application at my work-place, and need helping advise to resolve the issue.

The application which I am testing is having a dynamic error popup screen which loads from the top whenever any error comes in the application. To be more clearer, let's say I am entering Username and password to login into application, and I took wrong username and password combination. Now, due to this a dynamic error drop down comes from the top. I am saying it dynamic because, as soon as I am trying to inspect the element, the error screen fades away. Now, due to this, I am not able to locate the element.

Sometimes, I got lucky and was able to inspect the element by right-clicking on that element. But then as soon as I reach to element tab, Error screen fades away, and not able to inspect the element.

So, I need help here to know how can I handle this dynamic error screen.

Any help will be appreciated.  :-)

Comment: Well this can be frustrating. But, Use a recorder like "Katalon Recorder" to identify the locator for toast error pop ups.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use devtools to pause: 
 1. Open app in chrome 
 2. Open devtools 
 3. Go to Sources tab 
 4. Trigger error and press F8 to pause 
 5. Go to Elements tab and locate error html

Answer (score 0):

**Two quick ways :**

1. When you get lucky to reach until the elements tab after inspecting
   the error, just copy the total div/span/error element's html code.
   Paste it in a Notepad to locate the element with any strategy [like
   xpath/css].
2. If the above could not help, then ask the dev to make the dynamic
   error message to appear some more time and then you could locate
   them correctly.